# Does this decagon have a name?

Tags: geometry, tiling

Is anyone aware of a specific name for this decagon composed by the merge of two hexagons?

[image]

Comment: You might call it concave, or non-convex, or reentrant.

Comment: I mean a name for the exact shape. There are an infinity of concave decagons...

Comment: You could call it a "peanut" decagon.

Comment: ok I assume it does not have a specific name... if that's actually the case I think I will follow your advice!

Comment: In organic chemistry, this is a planar representation of *cyclodecane*

Comment: As a polyomino, one of the polyhexes, this is the unique bihex.